# How do I define time validation in model's rules function

Tags: validation, time, yii

i have a model appointment, want to define rules function in model to validate these conditions before submit

```
validation conditions:
start_time < end_time
end_time > start_time
start_time != end_time

    public function rules()
    {
       return array(
                    array('name, client_name, service_id, app_date, st_time, ed_time, appointment_status', 'required'),
                   );
    }
```

Appointment-table has following fields
id(PK), title, client_name, app_date, start_time, end_time, status

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [CCompareValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCompareValidator), you can define multiple rules for each of the stuff, and use the compareAttribute, and operator to define the compare rules.